# CSS media queries height

Tags: css, media

I just learned how to use CSS media queries to make my page fit the screen when the user re-sizes the window, or has a different screen resolution.

My page is designed so that the user won't have to scroll at all. 
I want to make my page to fit on 1280px by 768px and 1280px by 960px screen resolution.
The problem is, the page gets all messed up when I have similar widths (1280px).

Could someone please assist me? 
I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: "the page gets all messed up" - means what?

Comment: If I create a page for 1280 X 768, 1280 X 960 and 1280 X 1024, when I view the page in 1280 X 1024 the page is cuts off (height)

Answer (score 1):

You can setup styles between specific dimmensions. For example, something like this:

```
@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:979px){

<styles go here>

}
```

And then, anytime the viewport is between these two dimensions, your styles will adhere.

And I just realized how old this post is, but I'll go ahead and add it anyway in hopes it helps someone out.

Answer (score 1):

Use a comma to specify two (or more) different rules:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 995px) , screen and (max-height: 700px) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check out http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

It's an excellent guide on how to create multiple stylesheets for different resolutions.

Comment: Just to clarify, when I make two media queries with the same width, one cancels the other. 
How can I avoid this without changing the width values? 
Here is an example:

media screen and (max-width:1280px)and (max-height:960px) {

Content

}

media screen and (max-width:1280px)and (max-height:1024px) {

Content

}

media screen and (max-width:1280px)and (max-height:720px) {

Content

}

For some reason, the forum was not allowing me to post without deleting the "@" sign, so don't think I missed it.